# Power BI - Line Chart - Trend Comparison

Tags: charts, powerbi, dashboard

I have a line chart that tracks the fill rate performance of more than **50 suppliers** (Year/Month).My dashboard includes a filter for the suppliers.I would like to compare the performance of a given supplier against the collective performance of every one else.

Basically, I created this measure to calculate the fill rate:

```
3DAYS_FILLRATE = SUM(TBL_METRICS[SHIP3DAYS])/sum(TBL_METRICS[TOTALORDERS])
```

How can I create another measure that retains the performance trend of all the suppliers when the filter is applied?

Image of graph in Power BI is below:

[image: Fill Rate - Specific Vendor vs. All]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case that you are trying to filter a second visualisation containing the same measure and you are filtering using a slicer or other visualisation, you can click onto the visualisation you are filtering with, click on the 'Format' tab and click on 'Edit Interactions'. Then select none on the visualisation you wish to not filter. See Microsoft Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-reports-visual-interactions

[image]

Otherwise, you may be able to try creating the following second measure which could satisfy your needs:

```
Measure 2 = Calculate(SUM(TBL_METRICS[SHIP3DAYS])/sum(TBL_METRICS[TOTALORDERS]), all(tbl_metrics))
```

Comment: I created the following measure, and I add it to the chart, but for some reasons, it appears as a static line. Measure 2 = Calculate(SUM(TBL_METRICS[SHIP3DAYS])/sum(TBL_METRICS[TOTALORDERS]), all(tbl_metrics))

Comment: You may need to switch all(tablename) to allexcept(tablename,columnname) to allow for certain filtering on the graph, could you provide a screenshot?

Comment: Thank you for your assistance. I added a snapshot of the chart. Please see the original post.

Comment: Try the following, changing "DATECOLUMN" to your date column name - Calculate(SUM(TBL_METRICS[SHIP3DAYS])/sum(TBL_METRICS[TOTALORDERS]), allexcept(tbl_metrics,DATECOLUMN))

Comment: Hello MD, It is not only you answered my question, but you made me better understand DAX, and fall in love with it! Thank you very!!